# Generalized Stone Weierstrass theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Given a smooth function $f$ on some compact $K$ in the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$, does exist a sequence of polynomial functions $p_n$ such that $p_n$ and all of its derivatives converge uniformly to $f$ in $K$.

Thanks in advance

I just clarify that the convergence is in the sens that the  derivatives of $p_n$ converge uniformly to the corresponding ones of $f$ in $K$.

Comment: Are there some regularity conditions you are assuming on $K$ (e.g. boundary regularity) or are you really interested in full generality?

Comment: Assuming that $f$ is smooth in *some neighborhood* of $K$, yes. The trick is the usual one: convolve $f$ with a long Taylor sum of $c(A)e^{-A|x|^2}$ where $c(A)$ is chosen so that the full integral is $1$.

Comment: I presume you want the derivatives of $p_n$ to converge to the corresponding derivatives of $f$, not to $f$ itself as you wrote.

Comment: Assuming you want a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^d$ rather than a compact subset, you may enjoy L. Nachbin's version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem: 
``Sur les alg\`ebres denses de fonctions diff\'erentiables sur une vari\'et\'e.'', C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 228, (1949). 1549–1551. 
Let $M$ be a manifold of class $C^r$, let $A$ be the algebra of real functions of class $C^r$ on $M$ and let the topology in $A$ be that of uniform convergence on compact sets up to the derivatives of order $r$. 

Comment: Then a necessary and sufficient condition that a subalgebra $F$ of $A$ be dense in $A$ is that (1) for each $x$ in $M$ there is an $f$ in $F$ with $f(x)\neq 0$, (2) for $x\neq y$ in $M$ there is an $f$ in $F$ with $f(x)\neq f(y)$, (3) for $x$ in $M$ and a tangent vector $T$ at $x$ there is an $f$ in $F$ such that $Tf\neq 0$.

Comment: I do not see how to use fedja's answer to solve this  

Comment: I found also that the problem may be solved if we can construct a test function h satisfying: sup_{j\in\N, x\in K}j^{d+|\alpha|}|\partial^{alpha}h(j x)|< \infty  for all multi-index \alpha.